# Replacing local path backslashes with http:// forward slashes str_replace() in php

Tags: php, str-replace

I get the following result :`http://www.example.com/Music/\2011 Hits\Balle Lakka.mp3`

Following is `str_replace` to try and replace local path URL to `http://` path:

```
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
            $query = "SELECT songlist.* FROM songlist WHERE ID='".$song->ID."'";    
            $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
            $i=0;
            while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                while(list($key,$value) = each($data))
                    $arr[$i][$key] = $value;
                $i++;
            }

             $file  = str_replace("C:\inetpub\Music","http://www.example.com/Music/",$arr[0]['filename']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this,

Simply:

```
echo $url = str_replace("/\\","/",$url);
```

another method,

```
$url = str_replace("C:\inetpub\Music","http://www.mydomain.com/Music/","http://www.mydomain.com/Music/2011 Hits/\Balle Lakka.mp3");

$url = str_replace("\\","/",$url);
$url = str_replace("//","/",$url);
echo $url = str_replace("http:/","http://",$url);
```

Comment: http: should be followed by //

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = str_replace('\\','/',$file);
```

add it to the end. It should work..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<?php
$str='http://www.example.com/Music/\2011 Hits\Balle Lakka.mp3';
$str=str_replace(array('\\','//',':'),'/',$str);
echo $str;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
http://www.example.com/Music/2011 Hits/Balle Lakka.mp3
```

Comment: http: should be followed by //

Comment: You can avoid that with a negative lookback on http if you want... or, you can remove a trailing slash from the original url.. or the leading backslash from the file path.  I'm sure there are other ways.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran nope

Answer (score 0):

in while loop you can do following:

```
while(list($key,$value) = each($data))
    $arr[$i][$key] = ($key!='filename') ? $value : str_replace('\\','/', ltrim($value, '\\'));
```